# How to remove/hide a tab in customer admin edit in magento 2

Tags: customer, customer-account, magento2.2.4

HOW can we remove/hide a tab in customer admin edit in Magento 2 ?

For more clarification please visit here:-

https://nimb.ws/ZIxY8d

Waiting for the reply!!!

Comment: you need to study system.xml file.first try your own then i will tell you proper anwser.

Comment: i already tried that's why i posted here,i know about system.xml please let me know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got the place from where it's coming :-

```
vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml
```

Now,i've removed this element in my custom module by overriding "customer_form.xml" and it's working now.

--
Thanks!!!